# Get index of a column with the header of column (CListCtrl) mfc c++

Tags: c++, mfc

Every time i use IsertColumn function it will return an int variable. That variable is a index of a column.
If we have a lot of columns, is there any way to get that index of a column with given name (header text of that column).
Thank you

Comment: If you're looking for a method to call passing the column text of the header, it doesn't exist.  However, it shouldn't be difficult to write one on your own.

Comment: can you give me any suggestion to write that function ? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your request, something similar to this should work....

This example derives a CListCtrl to be used within a dialog.

```
int MyListCtrl::FindColumn(const CString& ColumnText)
    {
    int index = -1;
    CHeaderCtrl* pHeader = GetHeaderCtrl();
    if (pHeader)
        {
        int NumberOfColumns = pHeader->GetItemCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfColumns; ++i)
            {
            HDITEM Item;
            TCHAR buffer[256] = { 0 };
            Item.mask = HDI_TEXT;
            Item.pszText = buffer;
            Item.cchTextMax = 256;
            pHeader->GetItem(i, &Item);
            if (Item.pszText == ColumnText)
                {
                index = i;
                break;
                }
            }
        }
    return index;
    }
```

To call the function:

```
int index = m_llistctrl.FindColumn(_T("Value"));
```

Where "Value" is the text of an actual column in the header.

Answer (score 1):

[CListCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f7h7t7hd.aspx)**::**[GetHeaderCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8sdtw025.aspx)**::**[GetItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/82shyz02.aspx)(int iPos, [HDITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb775247.aspx)* pHeaderItem);

HDITEM::pszText is what you want - if I got your question correctly...

Comment: Thank you for that, your code is to get the header text of the column. I want to get the index of the column. But there is no function to do that, so i  may use your way. Can you give me an example how to use it.